# Concatenating and sorting two tables in one SQLite query

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having 2 tables:

**Table1**: ID,Type,form_date

**Table2**: ID, Type, form_date

Now, I want to fetch uniq date list (type wise) from both the tables and stores into the third table. How do I do such?

Date example:

Table-1:

```
Type    form_date
1       20/12/2010
1       25/04/2010
2       05/11/2010
```

Table-2:

```
Type form_date
1    20/12/2010
2    25/04/2010
2    05/11/2010
```

I want to have output as below:

**`Table-3 or Output`**

```
Type form_date
1    20/12/2010
1    25/04/2010
2    25/04/2010
2    05/11/2010
```

What can I try next?

### Update

From @dan04 answer, I am having success to store Type, form_date from both the tables.

But when I try to execute below query to get only form_date values then it is giving me an error:

```
SELECT form_date FROM Table1
UNION SELECT form_date FROM Table2
```

How can I have only form_date from both the tables?

Comment: What is the error it's giving you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Type, form_date FROM Table1
UNION SELECT Type, form_date FROM Table2
```

Also, store your dates in YYYY-MM-DD order so they'll sort correctly.

Comment: DISTINCT is unnecessary with UNION

Comment: Thanx for the support, now i have stored the date value in yyyy/MM/dd format and this query is returning result in SORTED order also. Thanx a lot for your quick support.

Comment: Can you please let me know that This is working for all the Type, but what if i want to fetch date valules of only Type "1" ?? Please help me.